# Erro de acentuação em PHP

Tags: php

Estou tendo problemas de acentuação em PHP.

No banco de dados é inserido com a acentuação certa, mas quando eu retorno pro PHP a acentuação não é retornada de forma correta, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="busca">
    <form action="">
    <input type="search" name="busca" placeholder="Buscar" id="busca" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="btn" id="btn">
    </form>
    <?php
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dict2");
    $busca = isset($_GET['busca'])?$_GET['busca']:"";
    if (isset($_GET['btn'])){
        $sql = "select * from tb_dict2 where def LIKE '%$busca%' OR trad LIKE '%$busca%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
        while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $trad = $linha['trad'];
            $def = $linha['def'];
            echo "<div class='content'>";
            echo "<h3>Português: ".$def."<br>";
            echo "Indonésio: ".$trad."<br>";
            echo "</div";
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente setar para utf8 seus carácteres pelo comando do mysqli.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="busca">
    <form action="">
    <input type="search" name="busca" placeholder="Buscar" id="busca" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="btn" id="btn">
    </form>
    <?php
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dict2");
    /* mudar o character set para utf8 */
    if (!$conexao->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $conexao->error);
        exit();
    } else {
        printf("Current character set: %s\n", $conexao->character_set_name());
    }
    $busca = isset($_GET['busca'])?$_GET['busca']:"";
    if (isset($_GET['btn'])){
        $sql = "select * from tb_dict2 where def LIKE '%$busca%' OR trad LIKE '%$busca%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
        while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $trad = $linha['trad'];
            $def = $linha['def'];
            echo "<div class='content'>";
            echo "<h3>Português: ".$def."<br>";
            echo "Indonésio: ".$trad."<br>";
            echo "</div";
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```